# Which SQL join should I use?

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I need to join them.

Here is my tables and what I need

[image]

Comment: What's the criteria to match rows of table1 with rows of table2 ?

Comment: @Aziz group and date should be equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
SELECT c.Data, c.Group, c.Count AS 'Users Count', a.Count AS 'Application Count'  
   FROM clients c 
   LEFT JOIN applications a
     ON c.Data=a.DATA
     AND c.Group=a.Group
```

[You can test it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b02/2).

Comment: I tried your code, but I don't receive expected output. Here is the my real tables and code that I used: https://imgur.com/a/nBkB4oD

Comment: I have just ran the same SQL query on your new tables, and [it is returning the expected results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5fc9f/1). What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Finaffteam Are you running the queries inside an application? Command line? or some management tool like phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a `left join`, to bring all rows from the clients table, along with available rows in the applications table:

```
select 
    c.date,
    c.group,
    c.count client_count,
    coalesce(a.count, 0) application_count
from clients-by_days c
left join applications_by_days a
    on a.date = c.date
    and a.group = c.group
```

If there are missing matches in both tables, the you need a `full join`:

```
select 
    date,
    group,
    coalesce(c.count, 0)client_count,
    coalesce(a.count, 0) application_count
from clients-by_days c
left join applications_by_days a
    using(date, group)
```

Not all database support `full join` (and not all support the `using()`) syntax for join predicates).